# Paint event of Picture box in windows form application not being called by iis hosted web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have created a Asp.Net Windows Form Application. The exe of this application is invoked by another Asp.Net Web API.

Whenever I run the WebApi on local, the exe is invoked and the paint event defined in the exe is executed and saves the result (here an image) at a particular location.

Code of WebApi to invoke the exe:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
Process p = new Process();
startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"F:\PolygonsMarking\howto_draw_polygons\bin\Debug\howto_draw_polygons.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = PolygonVertices.ToString() + " " + backgroundImage + " " + tile;//pass arguments to exe
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();//execute exe
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Code of Exe to accept arguments passed and call the paint event:

```
public Form1(string[] arguments)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (arguments != null)
    {
        BackImagePath = arguments[1];
        TileImagePath = arguments[2];
        string vertices = Convert.ToString(arguments[0]);
        polypoint = vertices.Split(',').ToArray();
        picCanvas.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(picCanvas_Paint);//call paint event                                   
    }                      
}
private void picCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@""+BackImagePath+"");//F:\PolygonsMarking\howto_draw_polygons\image2_1762.png");
    picCanvas.Image = img1;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(picCanvas.Image);
    LogWriter.LogFileWriter("\nin paint canvas");
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    //some code ahead
}
```

The code works fine when API is run on local, but when I host the Web API on IIS version 8.0 and run the hosted site the exe is invoked but the paint event code is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a workaround for making it work as required.
Instead of writing my code inside the picCanvas_Paint event I created a simple function with required arguments and called the same in place of calling the paint event.

And now the it works.